# Elasticseach get distinct year from date and document count

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data and request like this

```
"birth": "2003-02-01T15:00:00.000Z",
```

```
    "aggs": {
        "aaa": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "birth",
                "format": "yyyy",
                "size": 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want get the result as a list of year and the number of document for each year current result look like this:

```
                {
                    "key": 988556400000,
                    "key_as_string": "2001",
                    "doc_count": 2295
                },
                {
                    "key": 1375369200000,
                    "key_as_string": "2013",
                    "doc_count": 2284
                },
                {
                    "key": 1054479600000,
                    "key_as_string": "2003",
                    "doc_count": 2281
                },
                {
                    "key": 1183215600000,
                    "key_as_string": "2007",
                    "doc_count": 2276
                },
                {
                    "key": 1009810800000,
                    "key_as_string": "2001",
                    "doc_count": 2231
                },
                {
                    "key": 1170255600000,
                    "key_as_string": "2007",
                    "doc_count": 1695
                },
```

If key_as_string is the actual year so I expect it should contain only one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terms Aggregations will create bucket for each unique "birth" date and format field will only output year from that.

So you are getting duplicate values for year as underlying date are different.

You need to use [date_histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) instead. It will bucket documents based on an interval

**Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "birth",
        "interval": "year"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "NAME" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2003-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1041379200000,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2004-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", --> 2 docs under year 2004
          "key" : 1072915200000,
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

You can specify "format": "yyyy" if you want to see only year as key
**Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "birth",
        "interval": "year",
        "format": "yyyy" --> note
      }
    }
  }
}
```